# Zoom feature for Fotorama jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, zooming, lightbox, fotorama

Fotorama Magento has an inbuilt zoom feature for lightbox images. Is there a way to add a zoom feature for the lightbox image in the Fotorama jQuery plugin? I am using Fotorama slider on the PHP website.

Comment: Hey could u handle it ? Any solution ?